# Negated pattern in JFlex

Tags: java, parsing, jflex

I am using JFlex to parse strings. I have state `VARIABLE` where I want to parse everything between <...>

For that I defined this in my `.flex` file:

```
<VARIABLE> {
     [^>]+   {  return symbol(sym.VARIABLE, new String(yytext())); }
     ">"     {  yybegin(YYINITIAL); return symbol(sym.RVARIABLE); }
}
```

Unfortunately `[^>]+` does not work as JFlex does not match any string. Obviously simplification to pattern `[a-z]+` works correctly.

Thanks